# DOMElement empty nodeValue

Tags: php, html, parsing, domdocument

I have a project where I need to parse a xml page and pick out some data. The domDocument class seems perfect and I tried a few basic tests to see if it would do what I wanted.

Here is my code for the moment:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$html = file_get_contents('http://wadmag.com/feed.xml');
$previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTML("$html");
libxml_clear_errors(); //This here is to clear the errors caused by the page not
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value); // being proper html

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('item');
echo "Found : ".$links->length. " items";   

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->nodeValue."<br>";
}
```

Now the problem is that when I load the page, I get the message "Found: 21 items", meaning that the getElementsByTagName returned a list, but when I try to display the contents of the list, nothing is displayed, as if the nodeValue was empty.

The even weirder thing is that if I replace "link" in the getElementsByTagName by title or description, it displays everything as it should. Can't seem to understand why, the only difference I can see is that  and  might be proper html whereas  is not.

Comment: Your feed.xml is not HTML (which is SGML based) but RSS 2.0 (which is XML based). You should load it with `$dom->loadXML($xml)` or, more appropriate, directly with `$dom->load('http://wadmag.com/feed.xml')`. Apart from that, I cannot reproduce your issue. I get 20 items displayed when I run your code.

Comment: I just replaced $dom->loadHTML("$html") with $dom->load('http://wadmag.com/feed.xml') and tada ! Works perfectly.
I think that you could not reproduce the error because the Tag Name it should be looking for is "link" and not "item", I forgot to change it back after testing.
Thanks a lot ! I would accept your answer but I can't seem to find out how to do it yet.

Comment: These are comments, so you cannot accept anything. I didn't provide an answer because I could not reproduce your error. You can either answer the question yourself and accept that answer then or you can simply delete the question, since there really wasn't much to answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you parse XML, use `$dom->loadXML($response)` instead of `$dom->loadHtml($response)`